# File parsing with shell script

Tags: shell

```
[root@localhost sql]# cat a.sql 
use Test1;
aaaa
bbb
ccc
use Test2;
zzzz
dddd
use Test3;
jjj
use Test1;
kkk
lll
```

hi all i want to parse the about file into below way , i need to use shell script and can any one help me with script please. 
From the file it has to create a separate file based on ^use  and keep appending the next lines till one more use comes so the final output i need is

1 ) Three files need to be created

> Test1  Test2 Test3

2) if i cat the Test1 , Test2 and Test3

```
$ cat Test1
aaaa
bbb
ccc
kkk
lll


$ cat Test2
zzzz
dddd


$ cat Test3
jjj
```

please help me :-(

Answer (score 1):

While this may seem simple at first, to do it properly and handle initial test for existing files, truncation if the file exists, and also handle repeated entries to the filename at different parts of the input file -- takes a bit of work.

You need to track the filenames that have been created so far by the script, and if the same file is seen again, you need to continue appending to the file instead of truncating and beginning a new file.

Once you have the logic sorted out, the actual scripting isn't too difficult. While there are probably many other ways to do this, here is one way to meet your requirements:

**Adding Lines From Multiple Files**

```
#!/bin/bash

tfn='sqlfname.tmp'  ## tmp file to track filenames created across multiple files

while read -r line; do 

    if [ $(expr "$line" : "^use[ ].*$") -gt 0 ]; then ## begins with 'use'
        fname=$(expr "$line" : "^use[ ]\(.*\)[;]$")   ## filename after 'use'
        if [ ! -f "$tfn" ]; then    ## if tmp file does not exist create
            :> "$fname"
            echo "  creating $fname"
            echo "$fname" >> "$tfn"
            continue
        fi
        if ! grep -q "$fname" "$tfn" ; then ## check if filename in tmp file
            :> "$fname"
            echo "  creating $fname"
            echo "$fname" >> "$tfn"
        fi
        continue
    fi

    echo "    $line --> $fname" ## output to terminal (debug info)
    echo "$line" >> "$fname"    ## output to "$fname"

done < "$1"

exit 0
```

**Super Simple Version w/No Revision Control**

Also, if you don't care about keeping track of what files have been created, and *you* will be the one responsible for deleting/resetting the `TestX` files if needed, then you can use a very simplified version.

The only drawback here is there is no way to insure all `TestX` files start at a consistent point in time. That may be perfectly OK for you, but the reason for tracking the files in the first place was to guarantee a known starting point for the contents in each file.

From a script standpoint, without at least insuring that consistent point in time, the responsibility falls to the user (*you*) to delete all `TestX` files before beginning a final parse of all sql files to create them. But.. it does make the script very simple `:)`

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do 

    if [ $(expr "$line" : "^use[ ].*$") -gt 0 ]; then ## begins with 'use'
        fname=$(expr "$line" : "^use[ ]\(.*\)[;]$")   ## filename after 'use'
        continue
    fi

    echo "    $line --> $fname" ## output to terminal (debug info)
    echo "$line" >> "$fname"    ## output to "$fname"

done < "$1"

exit 0
```

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/sqlcreate.txt
use Test1;
aaaa
bbb
ccc
use Test2;
zzzz
dddd
use Test3;
jjj
use Test1;
kkk
lll
```

**Output**

```
$ bash parsecreatesql.sh dat/sqlcreate.txt
  creating Test1
    aaaa --> Test1
    bbb --> Test1
    ccc --> Test1
  creating Test2
    zzzz --> Test2
    dddd --> Test2
  creating Test3
    jjj --> Test3
    kkk --> Test1
    lll --> Test1
```

**Files Created/Content**

```
$ printf "\nTest1\n"; cat Test1; printf "\nTest2\n"; \
cat Test2; printf "\nTest3\n"; cat Test3

Test1
aaaa
bbb
ccc
kkk
lll

Test2
zzzz
dddd

Test3
jjj
```

Let me know if you have questions. The original version is moved below, in case you still need to draw from it.

**Adding Lines From A Single File (original)**

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a created      ## array to track filenames created

while read -r line; do 

    # if [ "${line%% *}" = "use" ]; then      ## test begins with 'use'
    if [ $(expr "$line" : "^use[ ].*$") -gt 0 ]; then
        # fname=${line##* }
        # fname=${fname%;}                    ## parse filename after 'use'
        fname=$(expr "$line" : "^use[ ]\(.*\)[;]$")
        entries=${#created[@]}              ## check number files created
        if [ "$entries" -eq 0 ]; then       ## if 0, truncate add to array
            :> "$fname"
            echo "  creating $fname"
            created+=( "$fname" )
            continue
        else    ## check all filenames in array
            for ((i = 0; i < entries; i++)) do
                [ "${created[i]}" = "$fname" ] && break  ## already created, skip
                if [ "$i" -eq $((entries - 1)) ]; then   ## if not, create
                    :> "$fname"
                    echo "  creating $fname"
                    created+=( "$fname" )
                fi
            done
            continue
        fi
    fi

    echo "    $line --> $fname" ## output to terminal (debug info)
    echo "$line" >> "$fname"    ## output to "$fname"

done < "$1"

exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks this works like a charm ,but one problem with this ..

this script will grep for any "use" string in all the line 
i have small condition which  we need to add here  .

if [ "${line%% *}" = "use" ]; then  

can we change something like this  if [ "${line%% *}" = "^use" ]; then 

using this cap "^use" only grep for the line starting with use . This way the code wiil not break can you please help on same

Comment: Ok, you are wanting to anchor `use` to the beginning of the line. You can change the type of test to `if [ $(expr "$line" : "^use[ ].*$") -gt 0 ]`  I'll update the script.

Comment: I also replaced the builtins for parsing `fname` with the regex match `fname=$(expr "$line" : "^use[ ]\(.*\)[;]$")` which is equivalent. The only drawback to `expr` is it is a bit slower than the builtins, but for small jobs (less than say 100,000 lines, it isn't that bad). I've left the original builtins commented out. Take your pick. If you are dealing with filenames that potentially have spaces, you should double-quote the entire command substitution (e.g. `fname="$(expr ... )"`

Comment: imagine if i have to parse the multiple files using your script
its over writng the first created file
example
we have two files  1) a.sql 2)b.sql

one i parse the a.sql and b.sql  the contents in both files should come under same file name
present everything is working file but unable to parse two files in a loop
it just over write the file contets ones  second file parsing is done
can you please help with that
i need the contents of multiple files in same file with same logic

Comment: Oh, now I'm confused. Are you saying you have multiple `sql` input files that may contain the same filenames that you can't overwrite the output files each time you run the script on a new file? If so, then we are going to have to use a `tmpfile` to hold the names of the files we create instead of an array. Instead of adding `fname` to the  array `created+=( "$fname" )` we will write it to a `tmpfile` (e.g. `if !grep -q "$fname" ; then echo "$fname" >> tmpfile` ) . Give me a sec and I'll see if I can write another real quick.

Comment: yes , correct  but the file name should be same and content of  file can be any multiple lines of different files .
The file name should be ^use Test ... so Test should be the file name

Comment: OK, try the variation under **Adding Lines From Multiple Files**, but **note:** you are responsible for making sure you reset/delete `sqlfname.tmp` as needed if you start a new run and need to start with a clean tmpfile. (the script is now POSIX compliant) Also, in these comments, to highlight code as code, just enclose it in `backticks`.

Comment: @sai also see **Super Simple Version w/No Revision Control** if you can take care of deleting/resetting the files that are created as needed. It can be done very simply without keeping track of any filenames -- but be warned, this will allow the files to get out of sync with each other if a unforeseen bug pops up.